# How to place permanent cursors in plot using matplotlib and pyqt

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, pyqt

I'm using pyqt and matplotlib to plot a bunch of graphs in a GUI. At this point I only have x,y coordinates on the bottom-right of the plot which dynamically change when I hover my mouse over a graph (this is a default function of the NavigationToolbar library in pyQt). This is what I see:

[image]

Here is some code for the Navbar -

```
self.mpl_toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self.mainFrame)
```

And this is the Navigation Bar I get on my GUI:

[image]

But I want a cursor function where I can click on the plot and I have a fixed x,y position like in matlab. See the image below for an example:

[image]

Is there a way to add cursors to the NavigationToolbar library? If so, how can I do this using pyQt?

I have looked at the pyQt + matplotlib documentation and all I can find is how to modify the NavigationToolbar to reduce the number of features on it.

Comment: You're right. For some reason I wasn't able to find this question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, the thread you linked only accounts for when the mouse hovers over the graph. I don't think it works when the user clicks on the graph.